# wp_get_object_terms - How can I order the resulting array by hierarchy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm returning a custom hierarchal taxonomy via wp_get_object_terms.

The trouble is that the results are being ordered by name or count, neither of which are proving reliable. (I'm using a custom taxonomy for "Location" - City, State, Country - sometimes the State appears before the City)

Is there a way I can order the resulting array by the custom taxonomy hierarchy?

Is there, perhaps, another way I should be looking at this?

Comment: Which solution did you go for?

Comment: What Kaiser detailed works well. Another option is to use term_order in the order_by.

Comment: I tried term_order but that seems to be ignored :( Look at : http://pastebin.com/RXMipMKE

Comment: Also the problem with Kaisers approach is that you need to know the categories which isn't really that flexible.

Comment: Hmm.. Try reversing the "order" to "DESC". What does that give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a rough sketch to get your idea:

- countries (hierarchical taxonomy)
- - France (country - sub taxonomy)
- - - Champagne (state - sub sub taxonomy)
- - - - Le Mans (city - term)
- - - - Angers  (city - term)
- - - - Nantes  (city - term)

And you want to order:

```
$query_results = query( 'country' => 'france', 'orderby' => 'state city', 'order' => 'ASC' );
```

Did i get this right? If not, feel free to edit my answer or update your Q.

Comment: @kaiser - I went another route to resolve this. Out of curiosity, though, have you tested this? It appears that you have two terms in the "order by".

Comment: I updated the Codex some month ago to show that it is possible. Just leave a `space` between two values.

Comment: Really! What is the codex reference? I looked on WP_Query and didn't see that. I want to learn more about this.

Comment: "Order & Orderby" Parameters: "Multiple" Example http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Does it prioritize based on the order you put it in? Also, it notes a comma - Can you use a comma or space interchangeably?

Comment: Just take a look at the function in core.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wp_list_categories` to sort out the hierarchy, it started supporting taxonomies as of 3.0.

You can see an example of using a custom taxonomy with `wp_list_categories` on the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy) for the function.

You'd just need to pass in the term ids from your `wp_get_object_terms` call to the `wp_list_categories` include arg, eg.

```
wp_list_categories( array( 'include' => $your_array_of_ids ) );
```

It should then list out the terms of your custom taxonomy in a hierarchal format, though it may not appear so if your theme isn't padding list elements(so be sure to apply appropriate styling if the results aren't showing in a hierarchal form).